# Get all items in list inside list with dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm still learning basic python and wanna ask how to get all items inside textDisplay if the list like this? thx before

```
dump_list = 

    [ [{'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Apple'}}], 
      [{'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Orange'}}, 
       {'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Grape'}},
       {'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Banana'}}],
      [{'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Avocado'}}]
    ]
```

I can only access them one by one

```
print(dump_list[0][0]['snippet']['textDisplay'])
```

and how to make output like this without print one by one:

```
['Apple','Orange','Grape','Banana,'Avocado']
```

Comment: What did you try? What is your problem exactly with this list? There could be very different things that cause you difficulties, so please clarify.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i've already update my post,

Comment: Giving your exact expected output is always a good thing, so that's better. But the main question remains: what is your actual problem? Do you know how to access a value in a dict knowing the key? An item of a list? To iterate on a list? And, as asked in a previous comment, is the structure of the list really so irregular, which seems strange?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille He didnt seem to know that iteratig a list is possible ...

Comment: i know list can be iterate, The problem I had before was where when using looping there was a list that was out of index @adirabargil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real complication is how to flatten a list, and this appears to be the most elegant option:

```
[t['snippet']['textDisplay'] for t2 in dump_list for t in t2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving the shorter way, this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand from the question, I think you want to print Apple, Orange, Grape, and so on.

Assuming that the length of the list can change and the length of lists inside the main list can also change, you can print the required text using the following python 3 code:

```py
mainLength = len(dump_list)
for i in range(mainLength):
    innerLength = len(dump_list[i])
    for j in range(innerLength):
        print(dump_list[i][j]['snippet']['textDisplay'])
```

Here we take main list's length and the length of lists inside it. While printing, we select the 'snippet' key to get the dict inside that, and them select the 'textDisplay' key to print the required string.

You can also store the output in a list instead of printing to print it as a list:

```py
outputList = []
mainLength = len(dump_list)
for i in range(mainLength):
    innerLength = len(dump_list[i])
    for j in range(innerLength):
        outputList.append(dump_list[i][j]['snippet']['textDisplay'])

print(outputList)
```

Comment: where previously i have tried to use looping but still couldn't so this is the correct looping, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to use a list comprehension with two loops:

```
data = [ [{'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Apple'}}], 
         [{'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Orange'}}, 
          {'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Grape'}},
          {'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Banana'}}],
         [{'snippet': {'textDisplay': 'Avocado'}}]
       ]

fruits = [dct['snippet']['textDisplay'] for sublist in data for dct in sublist]
print(fruits)
# ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Banana', 'Avocado']
```